# Return mulitple values in for-loop with order by

Tags: xml, xquery, element

I have two elements with same name in XML.
XQuery return gives error of sequence found

```
<baby>
    <name>america</name>
    <condtion>good</condtion>
    <style>4409</style>     
    <type>bear</type>
    <price>1.99</price>
    <birthday>none</birthday>
    <theme>inedependence day</theme>
    <theme>september 11</theme>
    <comment>none</comment>
</baby>
```

This is my XQuery expression:

```
for $x in collection("ty")/ty_babies/baby
where $x/theme!="none"
order by $x/theme
return concat($x/name,'     ',$x/theme)
```

I need XQuery to return both themes and maybe even more if more exist...

Answer (score 2):

Because you have two `<theme>` elements, you have to iterate over them like this (and put the `order by` in the second loop):

```
for $x in collection("ty")/ty_babies/baby
  where $x/theme!="none"
return 
  for $t in $x/theme 
    order by $t 
  return concat($x/name,'     ',$t,'&#xa;')
```

**Output is:**

```
america     inedependence day
america     september 11
```

---

To create some elements around your results, you can extend the above code to look like this:

```
for $x in collection("file:///home/kubuntu/Downloads/a.coll")/ty_babies/baby
  where $x/theme!="none"
return 
  <baby>
    {for $t in $x/theme 
       order by $t return 
    <theme>{concat($x/name,'     ',$t)}</theme>
    }
  </baby>
```

This returns

```
<baby><theme>america     inedependence day</theme><theme>america     september 11</theme></baby>
```

Comment: I changed my XQuery to the changes you made. I take it the '&#xa;' is what added the extra space in between the results. I like that ty. this works much better. I guess I need to find out now if I can display the two themes but the baby element only once

Comment: It is just for pretty formatting - it does add a linefeed (and return) after each entry.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate your additional requirements- maybe it inspires you.

Comment: that does help ever so much. I don't necessarily like the way it looks but I can work and play around with it to make it look like I had envisioned. again ty very much